# Nvidia - Digits error: Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cursor_new_for_display

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

On amazon server g2.2xlarge running ubuntu 14.04
I've tried to install Nvidia's digits. (after installing cuda, cudnn and caffe successfully)

But, When I try to run the file 'runme.sh' in the Digits-2.0 directory, I encounter the following error:

> libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394 PuTTY X11 proxy:
>   unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection
>   refused
>
> ** (digits-devserver:12172): WARNING **: Could not open X display PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network
>   error: Connection refused PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to
>   forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
>
> (digits-devserver:12172): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_cursor_new_for_display:
>   assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "digits-devserver", line 39, in 
>       config.load_config('quiet')   File "/mnt/yarin/digits/digits-2.0/digits/digits/config/load.py", line 147,
>   in load_config
>       option.apply()   File "/mnt/yarin/digits/digits-2.0/digits/digits/config/caffe_option.py",
>   line 232, in apply
>       import caffe   File "/mnt/yarin/digits/digits-2.0/caffe/python/caffe/**init**.py", line 1,
>   in 
>       from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver   File "/mnt/yarin/digits/digits-2.0/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 14,
>   in 
>       import caffe.io   File "/mnt/yarin/digits/digits-2.0/caffe/python/caffe/io.py", line 2, in
>   
>       import skimage.io   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/**init**.py", line
>   15, in 
>       reset_plugins()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py",
>   line 89, in reset_plugins
>       _load_preferred_plugins()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py",
>   line 69, in _load_preferred_plugins
>       _set_plugin(p_type, preferred_plugins['all'])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py",
>   line 81, in _set_plugin
>       use_plugin(plugin, kind=plugin_type)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py",
>   line 251, in use_plugin
>       _load(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py",
>   line 295, in _load
>       fromlist=[modname])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/matplotlib_plugin.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
>   109, in 
>       _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py",
>   line 32, in pylab_setup
>       globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from . import backend_gtk3   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py",
>   line 55, in 
>       cursors.MOVE          : Gdk.Cursor.new(Gdk.CursorType.FLEUR), TypeError: constructor returned NULL

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

My approach is less than ideal but it works.

Edit: `{caffe_root}/python/caffe/__init__.py`

Add the following lines to the top:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```